# Craft Commerce: Frontend Validation on Address Fields

Tags: validation, plugin-craftcommerce3, frontend-form

Yes I know there is [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15897/craft-commerce-validation-on-address-fields)

But how do you do address validation in the frontend of Commerce 3?

The problem is the way Billing Address & Shipping Address are set up.
Billing Address are the same form fields duplicated via js and it is next to impossible to differentiate the two.

If I add `required` to any field this will also apply to the hidden field in the billing address form. Therefore, the html5 validation will always fail.

Has anybody a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. I just add or remove the html5 `required` tag on load via Javascript. This way the js who duplicates the form can do whatever it wants and the html remains untouched:

```
// adds required tag to inputs on page load
  $("#shippingAddress-firstName").attr("required", "");
  $("#shippingAddress-lastName").attr("required", "");
  $("#shippingAddress-address1").attr("required", "");
  $("#shippingAddress-zipCode").attr("required", "");
  $("#shippingAddress-city").attr("required", "");
  $(".js-address-country").attr("required", "");

  // listens to billing address checkbox
  $("#billingAddressSameAsShipping").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      //removes required attributes when checkbox is checked (billing address form invisible)
      $("#billingAddress-firstName").removeAttr("required");
      $("#billingAddress-lastName").removeAttr("required");
      $("#billingAddress-address1").removeAttr("required");
      $("#billingAddress-zipCode").removeAttr("required");
      $("#billingAddress-city").removeAttr("required");
      $(".js-address-country").removeAttr("required");
    } else {
      //adds required attribute when checkbox is unchecked (billing address form visible)
      $("#billingAddress-firstName").attr("required", "");
      $("#billingAddress-lastName").attr("required", "");
      $("#billingAddress-address1").attr("required", "");
      $("#billingAddress-zipCode").attr("required", "");
      $("#billingAddress-city").attr("required", "");
      $(".js-address-country").attr("required", "");
    }
  });
```

Aditionaly the required tag is added or removed based on the Billing address checkbox.

This can be written much better I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

Would removing `required` via JS be an option?